# psint existe control de tipos?

Tags: pseint

Haciendo un pequeño ejercicio en PSEint:

```
Algoritmo Prueba
    Leer d1
    Leer d2
    toal <- d1 + d2
    Escribir 'Total: ', total
FinAlgoritmo
```

Me encuentro con el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe algun control de tipo de datos, ya busque en ayuda del programa en los ejemplos y no hay nada?

**La idea seria implementar un bucle hasta que la lectura del dato de entrada sea del tipo esperado.**

***Update:***

He intentado hacer una declaracion previa y esta revienta; el codigo en cuanto se intenta grabar un caracter Alfabetico:

```
Algoritmo Prueba
    d1<-0
    d2<-0
    
    Repetir
        Leer d1
    Hasta Que d1 es Entero
    
    Repetir
        Leer d2
    Hasta Que d1 es Entero
    
    toal <- d1 + d2
    
    Escribir 'Total: ', total
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los errores son de tipo 120 y 125; no veo manera de controlar el tipo de dato sin que reviente o se detenga la ejecucion del script.

***Update 2:***

intente como dicen en los comentarios declarara tipo ENTERO y no se pudo marco error de sintaxis:

```
Algoritmo Prueba
    Definir d1, d2 como Entero
    
    Repetir
        Leer d1
    Hasta Que d1 es Entero
    
    Repetir
        Leer d2
    Hasta Que d1 es Entero
    
    toal <- d1 + d2
    
    Escribir 'Total: ', total
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

Output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si declaras la variable puedes indicar el tipo que debería tener. `Definir d1, d2 como Entero`

Comment: @Mateo ya lo intente y no funciono mira la actualizacion.

Comment: @Mateo Ver el update 2

Comment: @Mateo la pregunta es si existen **CONTROL** de Tipos, **NO** **DEFINICION** de Tipos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseint tiene un conjunto de funciones predefinidas reducido. No parece haber una forma directa de saber eso.

Lo que sí puedes hacer es recibir la entrada directamente como una cadena de texto y verificar que todos sus caracteres sean numéricos. Una vez que tienes esa información puedes usar la función `ConvertirANumero` tranquilamente.

Por ejemplo puedes crear una función como esta:

```
Funcion res = EsNumero(str)
    lon = Longitud(str)
    res = Verdadero
    punto = Falso
    Para i=1 Hasta lon Con Paso 1 Hacer
        car = Subcadena(str, i, i) 
        Si car < '0' | car > '9' Entonces
            Si car == '.' & !punto Entonces
                punto = Verdadero
            SiNo
                res = Falso
                i = lon
            FinSi
        FinSi
    Fin Para
Fin Funcion
```

Nota: es tu responsabilidad pasarle a la función una cadena. De lo contrario espera errores.

Tu código se vería así:

```
Algoritmo Prueba
    Definir d1, d2 Como Cadena
    Leer d1
    Leer d2
    Si EsNumero(d1) & EsNumero(d2) Entonces
        total <- ConvertirANumero(d1) + ConvertirANumero(d2)
        Escribir 'Total: ', total
    Fin Si
FinAlgoritmo
```

Por cierto, escribiste mal `total` en el código original.